# Import class from module dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib

I have class called `'my_class'` placed in `'my_module'`. And I need to import this class. I tried to do it like this:

```
import importlib
result = importlib.import_module('my_module.my_class')
```

but it says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'my_module.my_class'; 'my_module' is not a package
```

So. As I can see it works only for modules, but can't handle classes. How can I import a class from a module?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It is expecting `my_module` to be a package containing a module named `'my_class'`. If you need to import a class, or an attribute in general, dynamically, just use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) after you import the module:

```
cls = getattr(import_module('my_module'), 'my_class')
```

Also, yes, it does only work with modules. Remember [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) is a wrapper of the internal [`importlib.__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__) function. It doesn't offer the same amount of functionality as the full `import` statement which, coupled with `from`, performs an attribute look-up on the imported module.

Comment: This is great! Another useful tip to use rpartition on string

```
class_path = 'my_module.my_class'
module_name, _, class_name = class_path.rpartition('.')
klass = getattr(import_module(module_name), class_name)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
import importlib
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def factory(module_class_string, super_cls: type = None, **kwargs):
    """
    :param module_class_string: full name of the class to create an object of
    :param super_cls: expected super class for validity, None if bypass
    :param kwargs: parameters to pass
    :return:
    """
    module_name, class_name = module_class_string.rsplit(".", 1)
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    assert hasattr(module, class_name), "class {} is not in {}".format(class_name, module_name)
    logger.debug('reading class {} from module {}'.format(class_name, module_name))
    cls = getattr(module, class_name)
    if super_cls is not None:
        assert issubclass(cls, super_cls), "class {} should inherit from {}".format(class_name, super_cls.__name__)
    logger.debug('initialising {} with params {}'.format(class_name, kwargs))
    obj = cls(**kwargs)
    return obj
```

Comment: Avoid code-only answers. Add some text to describe what is going on for people who might not understand it. Also, using `hasattr` with an `assert` is counter-intuitive; let `getattr` throw its exception instead.